# How to set notification alerts for users who posted threads in Discussion board in SharePoint 2010 ?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created SharePoint 2010 Discussion Board where users can post their threads.Now i would like to send notification alerts to that user who posted the thread whenever someone answered or modified his thread.How to accomplish this in SharePoint 2010.